# Is there a function for replace a value through the list?

Tags: python, list, replace

Currently, I'm working on a list like this

```
txt=['S&P 500 Index', '2,905.03', '+4.58', '+0.16%']
```

Since I need to convert all the numerical value into float rather than str, in order to use float(), I have to get rid of ',' and '%'. Is there a smart way to do this in a line?

Now,I'm doing stuff like this. Change everything by finding the exact index.

```
txt[1]=txt[1].replace(",","")               
txt[3]=txt[3].replace("%","")
```

I would like to see something like this

```
['S&P 500 Index', '2905.03', '+4.58', '+0.16']
```

Answer (score 1):

If the first element may not contain `%` or `,` you can apply the replace operations on it too without changing its value.

```
txt=['S&P 500 Index', '2,905.03', '+4.58', '+0.16%']                                  
txt = [s.replace('%', '').replace(',','') for s in txt]
print(txt)
```